# Next.js routing not working - Pages not loading correctly

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm having trouble with the routing in my Next.js application. I've set up one page with the name of `about.tsx` in the "pages" directory, but when I try to access it using its respective URL (`localhost:3000/about`), the pages don't load correctly and send:

> This Page Could Not Found 404 Error.

I've double-checked my code and directory structure, and everything seems to be in order. What could be causing this issue, and how can I fix it?

[image: next js folder structure]

Anyone can help me to fix this issue?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`app` and `pages` folders have a special meaning in Next.js](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/project-structure). Do not nest the two as you did. You choose which one you want while creating your project with the last question:

[image]

That `app` folder with a `page.tsx` shows that you have chosen `Yes` to the last question in the above image. And so, to have a `/about` route, you need to create a folder named `about` in `app` with a `page.tsx` in it, leading to `app/about/page.js`.

And if you are following along a tutorial and want to use the `pages` router, the easiest way is to create a new project and answer the terminal accordingly:

```
npx create-next-app@latest
```

Comment: This helped me figure out my 2 hour issue! Thank you.